# Assigning border over td is not working

Tags: html, css

I want to apply border over `td` like in the below image

[image: Img]

I tried it like below

**html**

```
<tr>
        <td class="label black-border" style="font-family: Courier New; font-size: 120%;" colspan="2">
            Survey No :
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurvey1" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; font-size: 120%;">
            Hissa No :
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHissa" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.black-border
    {
        border: 1px solid #3A86D2;
    }
    .label
    {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .field
    {
        width: 30%;
    }
```

But the border is not getting applied over the `td`

Comment: You want to show border to the first `td` only where the label `Survey No` comes or to the whole `tr` like the red border you put?

Comment: @PawanNogariya: to the whole `tr` as I  have shown in the image

Comment: it should work try inline style style="font-family: Courier New; font-size: 120%; border: 1px solid #3A86D2;"

Comment: @stack - ok, I have posted the answer, try it!

Comment: @HeadInCloud: I tried that too, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the class to your `tr` like this

```
<tr class="black-border">
```

and then have css like this

```
tr.black-border td
{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #3A86D2;
   border-top: 1px solid #3A86D2;
}

tr.black-border td:first-child
{
   border-left: 1px solid #3A86D2;
}

tr.black-border td:last-child
{
   border-right: 1px solid #3A86D2 !important;
}
```

Now, you don't need to use this class on `td` like your current code, you have to remove the class from your `td` and have to add it to `tr` only

Comment: yes, it is working. but what was the issue with my code ?

Comment: You were applying class to the first `td` element only while you need to apply this to all the tds of that tr with some modification like I did, for first and last child. Don't forget to mark the answer correct if it worked for you :)

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Comment: hi pawan, are u their, need a bit of small change..let me know once u come

Comment: actually when I increased the cell padding of the table , the look of the border got changed like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/SOczV.png. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zwL3a719/

Comment: Try this style in your table `style="border-collapse:collapse"`

Comment: hi pawan, I tried ur way but it is not working in IE

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `<table>` here... check this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/maky/qv1y11k3/2/

```
.border {
  border: 1px solid #3A86D2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will have to add border property to the table itself even if it means 0 border for the inner borders to be visible.

```html
 
 <style>
 .black-border
    {
        border: 5px solid #F00;
    }
    .label
    {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .field
    {
        width: 30%;
    }
 </style>
<table border="0"> 
 <tr>
        <td class="label black-border" style="font-family: Courier New; font-size: 120%; "  colspan="2">
            Survey No :
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurvey1" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; font-size: 120%;">
            Hissa No :
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHissa" runat="server" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And if you want for the whole  as per your picture. then put the class property in the `<tr class="black-border">`  and change the style to

```
tr.black-border td
{
   border-bottom: 5px solid #F00;
   border-top: 5px solid #F00;
}

tr.black-border td:first-child
{
   border-left: 5px solid #F00;
}

tr.black-border td:last-child
{
   border-right: 5px solid #F00;
}
```